# Replace Span Data with PHP and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

Im trying to do a simple span replacement using Jquery, php, and SQL. I think i coded this right but nothing is being displayed. I am using jQuery instead of $ to note the code to not collide with another script being used. How can i fix this:

jQuery:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.mysite.com/report/reportScripts/getData.php",
    data: "&id=<?php echo $_GET['repId']; ?>",
    dataType: 'html';
    success: function(data){
        jQuery('.msgbox').html(response);
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', '****', '****');

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("*****", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM report_ordered WHERE referenceNum = '".$repId."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $row['name'];
```

HTML Span:

```
<span id="msgbox"></span>
```

Comment: what is `response` in your ajax success callback? shouldn't that be `data`?

Comment: well, for starters you are defining an object named `data` and trying to fetch it by `response`

Comment: Careful, `echo $_GET[ ... ]` is [Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Success returns html in data, but you use response?

```
success: function(data){
    jQuery('.msgbox').html(data); # you used response 
}
```

### 2. You use className to find msgbox, but msgbox has id

```
success: function(data){
    jQuery('#msgbox').html(data); # you used .msgbox
}
```

### 3 . Use object as data: input in ajax

```
data: { id: <?php echo $_GET['repId']; ?> },
```

### 4. How do you fetch $repId? I hope you have some validation ?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM report_ordered WHERE referenceNum = '".$repId."'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your span has an id, not a class - refer to it as:

```
jQuery('#msgbox').html(response);
```

EDIT - as Johan pointed in above comment, if you define your success callback as `function(data){ ... }`, you have to refer to `data` and not to `response` of course.

Check your [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) for this kind of errors.